# Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSArray*' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsnumber

I am trying to fill my array with integer. However, there is something strange to me that it is not easy as I Thought. Here is the description of what happens.

Last line of the code gives me error. "Implicit conversion of int to NSArray not allowed"

```
//.h file
{
NSArray storeDisk[15];
}
property int virdCount;
property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *storeDisk;

//.m file

virdCount+=virdCount;
storeDisk[0]=virdCount;
```

Comment: You haven't created an NSArray.  You've created an array of NSArray pointers.  And storing @"101" is not storing an integer, it's storing a character string.

Comment: @s1m0n that would return an immutable array

Comment: And you shouldn't name an instance variable and a local variable with the same name.  The compiler will throw a warning and you will be confused.

Comment: The updates only dug you deeper.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I have updated

Comment: @s1m0n You probably meant to store it back into an `NSMutableArray *` or the compiler will barf when you try to add objects to it

Comment: Indeed, but I don't see why the original poster would want to specify a capacity since Objective-C will handle all of this for you when calling `-[NSMutableArray addObject:]`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to put an integer into an `NSArray`, you need to use `NSNumber`.

For example:

```
NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:virdCount]];
```

Or, there is the short-hand:

```
NSArray *a = @[@(virdCount)];
```

Either way, to get the data back out:

```
int value = [[a objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create an array by below way:

In .h file:

```
{
    NSMutableArray *storeDisk;
}
property int virdCount;
property (nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *storeDisk;

NSMutableArray *storeDisk = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[storeDisk addObject:virdLabel.text];
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a fundamental mistake of understanding NSArrays. I would suggest you read some iOS tutorials to learn the syntax and usage of core cocoa classes.

The following line:

```
NSArray storeDisk[10];
```

**Does not** produce an NSArray with 10 cells.

Neither will this work, as was in the unedited question:

```
NSArray* storeDisk[15];
```

That will simply produce an array of 15 NSArray pointers. That would be useful only if you tried creating an array of 15 NSArrays (and still, there would be better ways to do this in Objective-C).

You must read about NSArray and use the correct syntax to use it.
Other than that, NSArray is not the right choice since it is immutable. If you want to add objects to the array, you must use a mutable array. Second, to insert an integer you must use the cocoa wrapper for numbers - NSNumber. NSArray can only hold objects.

In order to produce an NSArray with 20 cells, one possibility is using this code:

```
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
[array insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:virdCount] atIndex:10];
```

Still, I **highly suggest** that you take a pause and read [some](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Objective-C_Array_Objects) [tutorials](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html) or [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Edited to reflect edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add int to array as it is. Array can only accept object so be it created using (id) or any othet objective c object. 
If you want to add int to NSArray use...

```
[arrayObj addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];
[arrayObj addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]];
```

Comment: Or [arrayObj addObject:@(0)];